# Eloquent MorphMany relationship proxy attribute

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

In my application I made the strange observation, that a seemingly equal operation has different results to another.

I have the following tables:

`aliases:`

```
$table->engine = "InnoDB";
$table->increments("id");
$table->morphs("aliasable");
$table->string("alias");
$table->string("locale");
```

`categories:`

```
$table->engine = "InnoDB";
$table->increments('id');
```

The `Category` model has a relationship to the `Alias` model:

```
public function aliases()
{
    return $this->morphMany("Alias", "aliasable");
}
```

When trying to manipulate the data of the alias of a category there is a difference between the two following methods:

```
$category = Category::find(1);
$alias = $category->aliases()->first();
$alias->alias = "test";
$alias->save();

$category = Category::find(1);
$alias = $category->aliases()->first()->alias = "test";
$category->aliases()->first()->save();
```

The first one is working, the second one is not saving the change.
I would like to get the second version working as I try to implement a proxy attribute on my Category model in order to change the alias like so:

```
$category = Category::find(1);
$category->germanAlias = "Heidi";
$category->push();
```

Do you have any idea why my way is not working as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing to understand here is the way relationships are cached on the model. When you access the relationship method directly, then no caching occurs. You are basically instantiating a new Query based off of that relationships definition.

```
$query = $category->aliases();
$alias = $query->first();
```

If you access the relationship as if it were a member/attribute of the model, then it will load and cache the relationship as a collection on the model.

```
$collection = $category->aliases;
$alias = $collection->first();
```

Future attempts to access the related model by this method will reference the same cached collection of models. This should work.

```
$category->aliases->first()->alias = 'test';
$category->aliases->first()->save();
```

Within **/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model** [__get()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L3261) is a magic method that redirects request for undefined members to the [getAttribute()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2548) method. The code comments do a pretty good job of explaining the rest but basically it checks for, loads, caches and reuses the relationships.

Comment: Thanks for clearifying the involved logic of caching. The problem with that is now, that I still would like to get my "proxy attribute" working. By this I mean an virtual attribute that somehow maps all changes to the related alias model with a specific locale.
`$category->thisMapsToGermanAlias = "Deutsch";`
`echo $category->thisMapsToGermanAlias;`

How would you do that?

Comment: You are looking for Mutators. Look at the first comment block in the getAttribute() method I linked above. You'll see that it checks for a "get mutator". Long story short ->germanAlias will be evaluated by ->getGermanAliasAttribute() if you define that on the model. Here is a link to Laravels docs on the subject. http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators

Comment: I read all that before, but I do not get it to work so that I have to save this attribute the same way as a normal attribute. Either I save it in the Mutator directly or the problem with caching reoccurs...

Answer (score 0):

```
$category->aliases()->first()->save();
```

This line select first alias and saves it. Doesnt actually do anything. Your first method is correct. You could also do

```
$category->aliases()->first()->update(['alias' => 'test']);
```

if your alias field is included in the `$fillable` property of the `Alias` model

EDIT

Run the code below and compare the object ids;

```
$alias = $category->aliases()->first()->alias = "test";
var_dump(alias);
dd($category->aliases()->first());
```

Comment: But why is the quoted line not saving the changes? I assume it is fetching the model again, discarding any changes. Is that it?

Comment: You are creating new instance of the fetched model each time.